# Can't package with Maven in remote host using Ansible

Tags: java, maven, ansible

I have a playbook with this task, among others:

```
- name: Compile and package
  command: './mvnw clean package'
  args:
    chdir: "{{workdir}}"
```

But I get this error:

> FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./mvnw clean package", "delta":
>   "0:00:00.003895", "end": "2016-12-29 21:59:16.121501", "failed": true,
>   "rc": 1, "start": "2016-12-29 21:59:16.117606", "stderr": "Error:
>   JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.\n  We cannot execute ", "stdout":
>   "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

If I access via SSH to the remote host and execute the same command, it works. `JAVA_HOME` is defined, obviously, but it seems that Ansible can't detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it says `JAVA_HOME` is not defined, it likely means `JAVA_HOME` is not defined.

First, when you login, you are using shell's interactive mode / login shell, when you use Ansible, you are using shell's non-interactive mode. Different rc-files are loaded for the two - refer to the "INVOCATION" section of `man bash` or [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) (it's similar for other shells, but I assume you are using Bash).

If `JAVA_HOME` variable assignment is in the rc-files which run only in interactive mode, you will have a discrepancy. Move the definition to the proper place.

Second, also depending on the place where you set `JAVA_HOME` - using `shell` module instead of `command` might load the proper definition file.

---

Just define the `JAVA_HOME` for this task with [`environment`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html) and do not rely on implicit inclusions..

Comment: Thanks! I understand the BASH_ENV now, to non-interactive shells. But where do I have to define the BASH_ENV? The `environment` solution is prctical, but imagine that in the future JAVA_HOME is different in each host...

Comment: Ok, in /etc/environment is loaded in non-interactive. It works :) Thanks

Comment: You are using declarative model, so define your configuration as it should be (and having a known and proper Java version is as essential in this case as having the correct environment variable) instead of relying on an unknown state "*different in each host*".